# error C4996 while building cocos2d-x Source code

Tags: c++, windows, cocos2d-x

i have just pull cocos2d source code from github, and try to build as win32 with command :

```
cocos gen-libs -p win32
```

And i got following error:

```
"...\tools\simulator\framworks\runtime-src\proj.win32\simulator.sln"
(1) ..... ....cocos\2d/CCSprite.h<474>: error C4996:
'cocos2d::Node::ignoreAnchorPointForPosition': was declared
deprecated...".
```

I'm running windows 7.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make some change because many of the methods have been deprecated.
Like in place of CCSprite we have to use only Sprite.
Many more changes have been made.
So by looking this much code its hard to give appropriate answer for your error.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of APIs and methods are declared deprecated once a safer and better version of them are released. You can still use them though. You just need to turn off your flag `Treat warning as error`.

For VS 2008,

> Project->Right Click->Properties
>
> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General
>
> Treat Warning As Errors : No

[image: VS 2008]